# LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync returning 500 first attempt

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure mobile services for authenticating my Windows 8 app. I'm using the MobileServiceClientExtensions.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync method to authenticate using a session auth token (code below).

My problem is that the first time I attempt to authenticate (after a lengthy period of time -- say 3-4 hours), the method will fail with a 500, "Internal Server Error" returned from the Azure service. Subsequent attempts seem to work fine. It seems like a timeout but the error is not consistent with that problem.

Has anyone encountered this and figured out a workaround?

```
LiveLoginResult result = await liveIdClient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
                if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    session = result.Session;
                    LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
                    LiveOperationResult meResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
                    loginResult = await App.MobileService
                        .LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);
```

Comment: Does the response contain any information about the error? Do you see any errors in the logs for the mobile service in the portal?

Comment: carlosfigueira, it doesn't. The other problem is that I can't reproduce it with any regularity so being able to dig into the problem is a challenge. There's also nothing in the service logs.

I discovered today that another user of my app is having the same problem. He tried to log in when he launched the app. It failed so he tried to log in again and it worked fine. So it doesn't appear to be environmental.